# Find Greatest Parent by recursion

Tags: php, arrays, function, recursion

I have a list of categories with sub-categories. A category can have up to 4 categories.
every category has an unique id and has a parent id.

I want to write a recursive function, adding an array of objects as first parameter and an integer as second parameter, this integer represents an id.

With this id entered i want to find out which is the most outter parent id.

For example here is the data structure:

```
$data = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name" : 'Main category',
        "parent": 0,
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name" : 'Sub Category 1',
        "parent": 1,
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name" : 'Sub Category 2',
        "parent": 2,
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name" : 'Sub Category 3',
        "parent": 3,
    },
]
```

I want to have a function `getParentId($data, 4)`

And the output would be

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name" : 'Main category',
    "parent": 0,
},
```

because the category with an id of 4 has a parent with an id of 3. The category with id of 3 has a parent with id of 2 etc.. As they are all related, the output would be the main category with id = 1 and parent = 0 as there is no more parent.

In real life I have hundreds of categories and each of them could have many sub categories nested

So far I tried by recursion something like that

```
function getParentId($repo,$id){
    $result = [];
    $data = $repo->findById($id);
    $data = $data[0];

    //base case
    if($data->getParentId() == 0){
        $result[] = $data;
    } else {
        $data = $repo->findById($data->getParentId());
        $data = $data[0];
        if($data->getParentId() == 0){
            $result[] = $data;
        } else {
            getParentId($repo,$data->getId());
        }
    } 
    return $result;
}
```

I am not sure why, it doesn't seem to play again until the parent is 0.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You don't do anything with the return value from calling `getParentId` recursively.

Comment: To me it seems like, in your recursion, i.e. the `else` block below base case, it should be `getParentId($repo,$data->getParentId());` [the part of else block nested inside it].

Also, check if `getParentId($repo,$data->getId());` should be `getParentId($repo,$data->getParentId());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out two different approaches, first using recursion:

```
function getRootCategory($repo, $id) {
  $category = $repo->findById($id)[0];
  if ($category->getParentId() == 0) return $category;
  return getRootCategory($repo, $category->getParentId());
}
```

And using a while loop:

```
function getParentId($repo,$id){
 $category = $repo->findById($id)[0];
                   
 while($category->getParentId() !== 0) {
 $category = $repo->findById($category->getParentId())[0];
 }
                          
 return $category->getId();
}
```